# i am unable to show the data from jtable to my textfield in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to get tha data from `JTable` but I am unable to do with these lines of code:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    d= (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    int c = d.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("number of cilumn is"+c);
    int selectIndex = d.getRowCount();
    System.out.println("selected row is "+selectIndex);
    jTextField1.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 1).toString());
    jTextField2.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 2).toString());
    jTextField3.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 3).toString());
    jTextField4.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 4).toString());
    jTextField5.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 5).toString());
    jTextField6.setText(d.getValueAt(selectIndex, 6).toString());
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: (1-)  What is the problem? Does the code execute? I suspect you get an Exception. If so, then the Exception should be posted with the question. We can't (always) guess what your problem is unless we have all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int selectIndex = d.getRowCount();
```

Above is incorrect for two reasons:

1. An index in Java is zero based. If your table only has 1 row and you try to use 1 as the index you will get an Exception.
2. The row count does not give you the index" of the row you clicked.

If you want the data in the row you clicked then the code should be:

```
int selectIndex = jtable1.getSelectedRow();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
 at javaapplication11.customerDetail.jTable1MouseClicked(customerDetail.java:282)
 at javaapplication11.customerDetail.access$300(customerDetail.java:25)
 at javaapplication11.customerDetail$5.mouseClicked(customerDetail.java:132)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
 .....GETTING THIS TYPE OF EXCEPTION .

Comment: The Exception should be posted as part of your question.